# How can I group by multiple resources in kendo-scheduler without repeating entries?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

I'm using kendo-scheduler JavaScript component for a planning webapplication, and I'm doing a vertical grouping of an Employees resource; this way I get a row in the scheduler's timeline for each entry in Employees resource, and I can move/add events to/beetween each Employee's timeline.

```
group: {
    resources: ["Employees"],
    orientation: "vertical" },
resources: [{
    field: "employees",
    name: "Employees",
    dataSource: employeeResourceFromJSON }]
```

What I want to do now is add a new "Role" Resource, and use that for groping purposes too.

```
group: {
    resources: ["Role","Employees"],
    orientation: "vertical" },
resources: [{
    field: "employees",
    name: "Employees",
    dataSource: employeeResourceFromJSON },
{ 
    field: "role",
    name: "Role",
    dataSource: dataRole }]
```

The result is I get on the leftmost column a list of Roles, and for every role on the column immediately on the right **each** Employee is shown.

Is there a way to choose wich Employees resources are shown in the Role subgroup? I'd like to code a list of Employees for each role, and then show only the Employees with a specific role under that specific role subgroup but I can't seem to find a way to do this with KendoUI tools.

I tried filtering bu I couldn't come up with a statement that made sense :)

Comment: Hi @Fabio , have you found any solution on this? I have the save problem as yours.

Comment: No, didn't find anything, but some kind of workaround came-up: what I did was inserting a "fake" value in my datasource. This value would have an attribute named "isGroup" and valorized either to "block" or "none". After this, I made a modification in the template for the scheduler: I put in some kind of button, with a graphical indication to make the user understand it is a group and what kind of group it is (group or role or whatever). When the data turned out to have isGroup = "block" this button is shown, since in the template i valored the button's "display" attribute = isGroup.

Comment: This button will then act as a group opener/collapser. @Hayu Rahiza

Comment: Mmh no sorry, I got confused, this is what I did to group in a Kendo List View, not in the Scheduler, sorry

Comment: Thanks for your quick response @Fabio